# Laravel 4 - Redirect back to the same page where the request comes from

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I want to redirect the user back to the page from where the request came. For example, a user tries to update his profile so edits the profile and hits SAVE. In controller I do the update and normally I would do `Redirect::to('profile')->with('message','Profile saved!')`. But what I want is to simply redirect it back with message. May be something like `Redirect::back()->with('message','Operation Successful !')` if this is available. I want it as it is more generic and I can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes this is available:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message','Operation Successful !');
```

But since this is a redirected request, you have to access the message by using:

```
echo Session::get('message');
```

Comment: ...awesome! I didn't know about that! Amazing!.... but, I still don't understand how to make this apper in my screen? Is like a view parameter, but instead of passing as a parameter, I call it by `Session::get('name');`. Is that correct?

Comment: and I was a minute too late ;) ... one tip for you @DennisBraga if you are uncertain of a Session variable's existence you can provide a fallback such as Session::get('name', 'fallback'). This has save me a headache or two.

Answer (score 21):

### In Short: Yes

You can certainly use

`Redirect::back()->withMessage('Profile saved!')`

in place of

`Redirect::to('profile')->withMessage('Profile saved!')`

**nifty feature in Laravel that it parses your camelCase on the `->with('name', 'value')` so that `->withName('value')` works just the same.*

#### Also....

I'm assuming your form is bound to the model such as `Form::model($user, [...]` to pre-fill form fields, but if not you may want to re-flash the input on the Redirect (or if your validation failed and you want to user to be able to correct the invalid info).

#### Just a snippet [untested]...

```
// [[... validation and other magic here]]

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()
        ->withMessage($message_fail)
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

return Redirect::back()
        ->withMessage($message_success)
```

Hope that helps!

Twitter: @ErikOnTheWeb

Answer (score 6):

You should consider not to use `Redirect::back()`. Yes, it's tempting and *seems* to be exactly what you need. But:

The `back()` method uses the "referer" attribute of the request header. So the user agent, usually a browser, tells the server (and Laravel) the URL he comes from. (as Wikipedia says: referer is a misspelling of referrer) **But not every user agent / browser will provide this information!** I use Opera and I do not allow it to transmit the referer in generally! So `back()` won't work for me. (Yes, I can allow this for a site but I'm way to lazy. And sorry, I don't trust your site.)

Comment: I hate to start a philosophical debate, but do you think that websites should cater to your rather specific configuration? I mean, if we have to constantly develop for "what ifs" and minority setups, we're creating a lot of overhead that's not even useful in the average case.

Comment: I don't know if it's a real problem or if 99% of all users have it enabled, therefore I cannot give you an answer.

Comment: This isn't really an issue since 99.99% of users don't really have this configuration so its isolated down to the individual person.

Comment: You seriously are paranoid to the point of not transfering referrer? I understand all the no ads, no tracking, no cookies thing and all the security they make you lose, but what's wrong about the website knowing the referer was itself, or it knowing you came from google? how is that a privacy breaking information enough that you would take time to change that setting?

Comment: And if you test your code, it makes it harder, as you will generally just check one request at a time, meaning you gave to provide the referrer.

Comment: There's also security implications: a malicious user could put whatever they like in the `Referer` header.

Comment: is there any solution for this issue ? I have a big project and i cannot change redirect from everywhere.

Comment: @Flimm Yes, a malicious user could put anything they want in it, but it wouldn't accomplish anything.  All that would happen is they would redirect themselves to whatever URL they put in the Referer header.

Answer (score 3):

```
return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Profile saved!');
```

Or,

```
return back()->withMessage('Profile saved!');
```

or

```
return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Profile saved!');
```

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel 8 just use:

```
return back();
```